# Proof of an inverse function inequality.

Tags: derivatives, inverse-function

It is given that $f$ is a monotonically increasing function 
$\forall x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f''(x) \gt 0$.

Provided that $f^{-1}$ exists, It is to be shown that, 
$$\frac{f^{-1}(x_1) + f^{-1}(x_2) +f^{-1}(x_3)}{3} \lt f^{-1}\left(\frac{x_1 +x_2 +x_3}{3}\right)$$

I assumed that $f^{-1}(x)$ is the mirror image of $f(x)$ about the origin, it must have all values of its derivatives negative, since $f$ is monotonically increasing. Is this correct? If not, how can the above be proved?

Comment: The condition you have written will hold if $f^{-1}$ is strictly concave. If you visualize what $f$ looks like (increasing, $f''(x)>0$), you can see that this should hold.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality you want is a consequence of [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Since $f$ is strictly convex we get that

$$\frac{f(y_1)   + f(y_2)   +f(y_3)}{3} >f(\frac{y_1   + y_2+y_3}{3})$$

Now set $y_i=f^{-1}(x_i)$

So the previous transforms to

$$\frac{x_1  + x_2   +x_3}{3} >f\left (\frac{f^{-1}(x_1)+f^{-1}(x_2)+f^{-1}(x_3)}{3}\right )$$

Since $f$ is increasing so is $f^{-1}$ so applying $f^{-1}$ to the previous inequality we obtain the desired inequality namely

$$f^{-1} \left (\frac{x_1  + x_2   +x_3}{3} \right ) > \frac{f^{-1}(x_1)+f^{-1}(x_2)+f^{-1}(x_3)}{3}$$